# Subselect in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am looking for the dplyr equivalent of the following SQL:

```
SELECT x
FROM ABT1
WHERE x IN (SELECT z FROM ABT2 WHERE q = ABT1.q)
```

I need this to be able to add a new column to a data frame based on values in an other data frame. I might be doing this the wrong way (hope you can tell me), but the idea I have is along the lines of:

```
ABT1 <- ABT1 %>% mutate(x = ifelse(ABT2 %>% filter(x = ABT1.x) %>% count() > 0, 0, 1))
```

The code above does not work as I don't know how to finish it. ABT1 and ABT2 are both data frames.

Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `dplyr`, we can do

```
library(dplyr)
inner_join(ABT1, select(ABT2, q, z), by = 'q') %>%
       filter(x %in% z) %>%
       select(x) %>%
       distinct()
#  x
#1 4
#2 3
```

-testing with 'sqldf'

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf('SELECT x
 FROM ABT1
 WHERE x IN (SELECT z FROM ABT2 WHERE q = ABT1.q)')
#  x
#1 4
#2 3
```

#### data

```
ABT1 <- data.frame(q = rep(letters[1:3], each = 2), x  = c(1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 3))
ABT2 <- data.frame(q = rep(letters[2:4], each = 3),
           z = c(4, 9, 12, 3, 1,  4, 10, 6, 5))
```